# dynamically generated table did not display

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<table>
    @if (Model.Logs != null && Model.Logs.Count > 0)
    {
         <tr>
            <th>Operation Name</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Parameters</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Operation Time</th>
        </tr>
        foreach (var log in Model.Logs)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => log.OperationName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => log.User)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => log.Parameters)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => log.Comment)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => log.OperationTime)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

I'm trying to query some data from db and show them in a table via MVC. I set breakpoints and the codes seem to work well. But at last, the table didn't show on the page as expected. What's the possible reason? Thanks.

Comment: Can it be that the if statement returns nothing; that the statement is false?

Comment: It means that `Model.Logs` is `null` or contains no items

Comment: The statement is true, and Model.Logs contains items.

Comment: Then it WOULD generate the html for the table!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is looping when you put break point? If it does, try this. Make sure looping.

```
<table>
        @if (Model.Logs != null && Model.Logs.Count > 0)
        {
             <tr>
                <th>Operation Name</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Parameters</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th>Operation Time</th>
            </tr>
            foreach (var log in Model.Logs)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@log.OperationName</td>
                    <td>@log.User</td>
                    <td>@log.Parameters</td>
                    <td>@log.Comment</td>
                    <td>@log.OperationTime</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </table>
```

Comment: This can't be the answer if the hole table did not display! Your answer could work if the headers worked.

Comment: What's the possible matter then?

Comment: Many possible reasons. Maybe your html table hidden or covered by another element. Show another elements? Put <h1>testing</h1> at the top of your page to know it is rendering page or not.

Comment: Maybe you can put else statement and output somethings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change the if-statement to a working statement where it returns something. I probably returns nothing at this moment.